# Are there any non-human "races" or characters that also have never been and will never be human?

Tags: bleach

It seems like every character and "race" in Bleach is either human, was human at one point, will become human when they die, or were born to those who were at one point human - Shinigami, Hollows, etc. all seem to be, in some way, at least partially human or destined to become human.

Are there any races or characters that are truly non-human in any way shape or form?

Comment: I don't understand the thrust of the question here...are you questioning why there *aren't* extraterrestrial characters or beings in the Bleach universe?, or if there are?

Comment: I'm curious if there ARE races outside of humanity - like demons or yeah, aliens I guess. It seems like everyone in the show is, was, or will be human at some point - I was wondering if that's the case, or if there are truly non-human characters. It's a confusing question and I wasn't sure how best to word it, sorry.

Comment: Would Zanpakuto count? How about mod souls? Neither are, were or will ever be human, both I guess fall into the same category as homunculi, artificial beings given life through science/sorcery. Zanpakuto are sentient swords crafted by a dude which can appear in human form as Asauchi, spend most of their time silently and namelessly as swords and can be named and conversed with by a select few. Mod souls (canonically only Kon) are artificially created souls which appear as small candy and can be stuffed into things to possess them like people, gigai and stuffed lion plushies

Comment: Yup they count, thanks for the answer! I was just kind of hoping there'd be more beings that weren't human

Comment: @Gatchwar: I think clarifying questions are fine as comments, but you may want to convert the rest of your comment into an answer instead given that the author has agreed that they count.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Every entity in the world of Bleach is or was either subject to be made from some component of souls, which would be tied back to some component of a human.

Even with modified souls being put into the fray, they were originally made in Soul Society with the available materials at hand (i.e. [*reiryoku*](https://bleach.fandom.com/wiki/Reiryoku)), so even the modified souls would still be some fragment of a human.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the point made about reiryoku (spiritual power), did you mean reishi (spiritual particles) by any chance? My understanding of the "physics" of Bleach is terrible but reiryoku seems more like an attribute than a physical thing. i.e. things in our world have attributes like colour, texture and mass but none of these are physical "things" unto themselves. "Blue" is not a "thing" but a blueberry is, "things" aren't made of "mass" they're made up of elements/atoms/etc. and the amount of stuff in an object is its mass. I think reishi is the thing that reiryoku measures